# How to set a value to scope object.object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How to set value and get the value in the form of **$scope.object1.object = "some data";**

In html and js if i set data like this it will work.

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors">

 $scope.colors = [
          {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
          {name:'white', shade:'light'},
          {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
          {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
          {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
        ];
```

But actually i want like these

```
 <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in test.colors">

  $scope.test.colors = [
          {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
          {name:'white', shade:'light'},
          {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
          {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
          {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
        ];
```

See the Example in [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/g5mGdHP5LHY8Y1xiP9rm?p=preview)

Comment: Please post code within question, not just in external link. Also question needs a  bit more effort to be clear what your issues are. WHat does `jsp` have to do with anything here?

Comment: what kind of issues are you getting? test is undefined?

Comment: I am not getting any error and also i updated plunk url. now what i want exactly is while setting data i want to set like $scope.test.colors = data;  and in HTML i want to access like test.colors

Comment: click on this http://plnkr.co/edit/g5mGdHP5LHY8Y1xiP9rm?p=preview url. here i am not able to see the data in dropdown. while setting $scope.test.colors it is causing. if you set $scope.colors it will work.

Comment: Hi now i updated can you see and provide the solution

Comment: the error if because your test is not define.. you need to do something like:

$scope.test = {};
$scope.test.color = [];

now should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OPk4tZi0RyoXj534nyqJ?p=preview)

```
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // ADD THIS NEXT LINE
    $scope.test = {}
    $scope.test.colors = [
      {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'white', shade:'light'},
      {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
    ];
    $scope.myColor = $scope.test.colors[2]; // red
  }]);
```